# Running a background task

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I currently have a very labor intensive function called "RestoreEmail" so I've put it into a thread on the webpage like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RestoreEmail());
```

However, I'm finding that if the person using the webpage doesn't sit and wait for it to process (they close the browser window or move to a different page) it doesn't restore the email and all is lost. I had this problem once a while back on a different project and I called an external page that then would process the function. Would this work better for my current situation? If I was to do this how exactly would I call the external page? I don't want the page to wait for the data to download because I presume it will yet again wait for the RestoreEmail to process.

Comment: Don't do "background tasks" in ASP.NET. Leave such things for a Windows Service, or a Scheduled Task or something. A recent similar question brought up Quartz.NET.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".